# How to add my existing html project into play framework

Tags: playframework

I am new to Play framework. Right now I have an existing html project that includes css, js, html. I am wondering if there is a easy way that I can simply add my project to play framework. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Sure! Download one of the starter or seed projects and then put your files into the `public` directory. When you start the Play server your files will be visible.

- Download info: https://www.playframework.com/download
- Info on public assets: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsOverview

Comment: It seems like no other way but change the reference of my files such like js, css in html into play way after I copied it to the public folder. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean…

Comment: If you mean the fact that you need to access `/public/file.js` at `http://myserver/assets/file.js`, you can remove the `assets` prefix by editing `conf/routes` and changing `GET  /assets/*file` to `GET /*file`.